# Something wrong with my Minecraft!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Okay my minecraft graphics seem to be spazzing out. I keep getting black flashing on mobs, and the pc, as well as chests and signs. Nothing else that I know of is spazing.

I was able to play it fine two days ago before my pc got a virus and I had to reset to factory settings. And I seem to be having issues with my memory running out. This didn't happen before either.

I'm using minecraft 1.2.5 and i got a ati radeon x1600 card. Need anymore info ask.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really gaming-related, but more a tehcnical issue...

A few hints thus:

1. Since your computer was reset, I assume the **drivers** were returned to "windows / factory defaults". Try upgrading them all.
2. Are you using a modded Minecraft? If yes, maybe a **new mod** is causing problems.

Anyway, if you're not using it yet, I strongly recommend using [**Optifine** HD Standard mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-125-optifine-hd-b1-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-much-more/) (Other versions are nice too, but I had more problems with those). It doesn't really mess up with anything, and provide extreme graphic performance increase. This mod is very easy to manage with [the Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-097-mods-options-news/) for Minecraft.

*Nota: I am not sp614x, and am not advertising myself here... However, dear reader, if you are, I salute you.*

Comment: Maybe he can try to update the JVM too.